# Annoying error: pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently started using Pygame but I came across this error and can't seem to find a reason as to why this has happened.

My code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,500))
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            done = True
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The error I get:

> ```
> pygame.error: video system not initialized
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a small error write `pygame.QUIT` instead of `pygame.quit()`. This causes pygame to quit, so the error makes sense.